# How does photovoltaic effect work?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

If I understand it correctly, due to diffusion and something like a concentration gradient, a gate layer is formed at the PN junction (at P there is more space=holes, at N there are a lot of packed electrons). This overflow of electrons from N to P is then inhibited by the emerging electric field — equilibrium is reached between the diffusion and electric field.
But I don't understand the photovoltaic phenomenon. If an electron is excited in the gate layer by the influence of a photon, why would it be significantly pulled by this electric field to the semiconductor N, thus creating a voltage between the two poles, as is explained on the internet?
I mean, shouldn't this movement of the excited electron actually decrease the electric field and disturb the equilibrium — wouldn't thal lead to backwards flow of the electrons? I don't understand how this can create voltage. Wouldn't the excitation just speed up both directions of flow at the same time? How can it change the equillibrium?

Comment: Yes, you can make so many electron-hole pairs that you overwhelm the built-in potential in the depletion layer. That takes much more power than the sun provides.

Comment: But why would these photon-generated free electrons want suddenly to leave the P if they previously decided to sit there? Is it, perhaps, that after connecting N and P, the free N electrons randomly bump into P holes and after getting there, they can't go back? And only after being excitated via photons, they can move back via the potential? But wouldn't this just lead to the PN-junction and potential being cancelled? That would mean we have neutral N and P without any PN-junction and any potential as in the beginning? How can they have voltage?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the external connections of the cell. If you have no external connection, the electron-hole pairs collectively charge the cathode and anode, reducing the field in the depletion region to the point where the equilibrium is indeed equal currents in both directions. Externally, you measure a potential across the cell: the "open circuit voltage".

But if you connect a wire across the cell, the whole photocurrent flows through the wire: the "short circuit current". The cathode and anode are not allowed to accumulate charge in this case.

The cell delivers no power in these cases: power is the product of voltage and current. Modern photovoltaic systems incorporate "maximum power point trackers" that externally control the potential across the cell to a level where the decrease in the depletion field doesn't reduce the external current very much. There's an optimum point where the power is maximum, and an MPPT incorporates an algorithm to find it.